# Why did this question on meta, related to a question which got 2 down votes on the main site, get 4 down votes and no answer?

Tags: discussion

Why did this question on meta, where one - as the help center says - can ask things to improve their attitude to stay well and better on ELU, get 4 down votes and no answer?

How does it works this community?

[image]

Comment: Please, please, please ask a meta question on why this one is downvoted.

Comment: Downvoted because [too meta](https://xkcd.com/1447/).

Answer (score 13):

Downvotes on meta are more an indication of disapproval or disagreement than (as on the main site) "not useful"; they do not affect your reputation.

But each downvoter has his own reason, which is not vouchsafed to the rest of us; there is no way that anybody can tell you the reason for any particular vote.  If you made an honest attempt to improve, some of us might make suggestions; but demanding explanations, ignoring a request to post links rather than screenshots, and not bothering with basic grammar, are no way to ask for help.

All this has been said before, and most of it is on the help site: somebody who has been here for 3 years really should not have to ask a question like this.

Comment: True, *each downvoter has his own reason*, and we can't necessarily assume any specific motivation for any particular vote. But as I write, there are exactly 10 downvotes for the question, 10 upvotes for your answer, and 10 upvotes for [@Mitch's amusing comment](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/why-did-this-question-on-meta-related-to-a-question-which-got-2-down-votes-on-t#comment26445_7017). So I'm tempted to assume that 10 people all voted the same way, each casting three votes (and that the comment is *pure sarcasm* - we don't really want yet another one! :)

Comment: @FF: I happen to know that your  tentative assumption is ill-founded, though I do not propose to discuss why. (Also, are you sure about sarcasm? It would be artistically satisfying to have yet another such complaint, though  undesirable in other ways.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...I want yet another one. One post and it's an annoyance. Two, and it's an outrage. Three, it's a habit. At four, it's a tradition. And at five, we will officially have a cultural institution. Why do you hate culture so, FumbleFingers?

Comment: @Parthian: Circumstances alter cases. It's not obvious to me that being inculcated into *German* socioeconomic culture has done the Greeks any good. On the other hand, *yeast* culture gives us stuff like bread and wine, so I guess it's not all bad.